# How do I connect a row with one another and order them alphabetically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see the image first.

{image: https://i.hizliresim.com/8NRGrV.png}

I want to connect the rows TR and EN, so like yatırım >> invesment and I want them to go together wherever I put them and after that I want to list them alphabetically, just like dictionary. Is it possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLs2H.png) what you mean? What is it exactly what you want?

Comment: image cannot be opened. :/

Answer (score 0):

Select all items (click one item in list and ctrl+a) and make table (insert>table). Make sure that my table has headers option checked. Now you can sort them alphabetically and all of them are connected so they change together. For sort you can use dropdown in headers.

Bütün objeleri seç. Tablo oluştur (ekle>tablo) tik işaretli olsun şuan türkçesini hatırlayamadım. Sonra nerden sıralamak istiyosan o başlıktaki açılır butona bas sırala de. Zaten tablo olduğu için hepsi artık birbirine bağlı en ve tr otomatik takip eder.

Comment: It did all I asked for but, it messed up my design and everything. (merged cells etc.) Isn't it possible do it without messing up the design?

Comment: If you don't want instert table you can just sort them. Select column that you want to sort and press ctrl + a. Then right click and sort. Your other columns  will still connected each other.